# Dealing ASP.net Routes with n slashes using regex

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, routes

I need to use a URL like this:

**http://mydomain.com/Box/Categ1/Categ2/Categ3/.../CategN/id1,id2,id3,...,idN**

Then I tried to create a new route this way...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Box",
    "Box/{data}",
    new { controller = "Box", action = "Index"},
    new { data = @"([a-zA-Z0-9-,]+/?)+" }
);
```

But it just doesn't work. If I use any char instead of "/" (slashes) it works fine. Is it possible to use the slashes? I really would like see the URL like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to set the data variable to everything that comes after Box, just use the catch-all parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Box",
    "Box/{*data}",
    new { controller = "Box", action = "Index"}
);
```

Comment: No problem.  By default, the asp.net mvc routing engine separates everything into tokens using the slash as a divider... so I'm not sure how it would work in regular expressions, but probably not well ;)